# Haskell: How to access individual elements of Linear.V or Linear.Matrix using indexed lenses?

Tags: haskell, linear-algebra, haskell-lens

I'm learning how to use [linear](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.21) and from the few tutorials I've found it looks like it is designed to work with [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens). I'm a beginner with both (and Haskell too, frankly).

In my case I just want to access (and eventually modify) single elements in [`V4`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.21/docs/Linear-V4.html) vectors, and [`M44`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.21/docs/Linear-Matrix.html#t:M44) matrices.

So far I've managed to access elements with the `_x`, `_y`, `_z` and `_w` lenses defined by `Linear.V4`:

```
λ> import Linear.V4
λ> import Control.Lens
λ> view _x (V4 1 2 3 4)  -- equivalent to V4 1 2 3 4 ^. _x
1

λ> m = identity :: M44 Double
λ> view _x $ view _y m    -- access element [row=1, col=0]
λ> m & _y . _w .~ (2.0)
V4 (V4 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0) (V4 0.0 1.0 0.0 2.0) (V4 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0) (V4 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0)
```

However there are two related things I need to understand to proceed from this point.

### Part 1

How do I translate that last "set" operation to use word-named Lens functions?

For example:

```
λ> set _w (2.0) $ view _y m
V4 0.0 1.0 0.0 2.0   -- returns a V4 not a V4 (V4 Double)
```

I also didn't have much luck with this kind of approach:

```
λ> (view _w $ view _y m) .~ 2.0
• Couldn't match type ‘Double’
                 with ‘(a0 -> Identity Double) -> s -> Identity t’
    arising from a functional dependency between:
      constraint ‘mtl-2.2.2:Control.Monad.Reader.Class.MonadReader
                    (V4 (V4 (ASetter s t a0 Double))) ((->) (M44 Double))’
        arising from a use of ‘view’
      instance ‘mtl-2.2.2:Control.Monad.Reader.Class.MonadReader
                  r ((->) r)’
```

I assume I need to combine the set and view operations with the two lenses somehow, so that they form a single reference to the element concerned, but it's not clear to me how to do this and I can't find any appropriate examples.

### Part 2

How do I use indexed lenses to access elements of a `V4` or `M44`? For example, if I need to access element [2, 3] rather than `_z` followed by `_w`? I see that `V4` is an instance of type-class `Ixed` so after some reading I thought I might be able to do the following:

```
λ> (V4 1 2 3 4) ^. (ix 2)
• Could not deduce (Num (Linear.Vector.E V4))
    arising from the literal ‘2’
  from the context: (Num a, Monoid a)
    bound by the inferred type of it :: (Num a, Monoid a) => a
```

I can't make head-nor-tail of that error message.

To bring those two parts together, what I want to be able to do is get/set individual elements of an `M44 Double` matrix, and if `Lens` is the only/best option then I'd prefer to write my Lens-based code using the descriptive names for Lens functions rather than a fruit-salad of punctuation, at least until I have more experience with the library.

### EDIT:

To be clear, the indexing needs to be performed at run-time. The motivation for this is that I have an existing (pretty simple) matrix abstraction layer that has a set of existing unit tests, some of which check individual matrix elements for near equality, sometimes as part of runtime loops. The abstraction layer currently uses a naive matrix implementation which is pretty slow, so I want to integrate a performance library like `Linear` into the abstraction, but to do this I need to support runtime indexed addressing to have the tests pass.

Comment: Don't know about part 2, but for part 1 you just use `set` with the composition of the two lenses: `set (_y . _w) 2.0 m`

Comment: What's your actual goal in part 2? That `Ixed` instance looks like it's there to support working with indices returned by previous indexed traversals, not to turn arbitrary input numbers into indices. It looks like `linear` really doesn't want you to think of its values as numerically indexed. So what are you doing that's leading you to try to do that?

Comment: @Carl good question - my goal is to integrate `Linear` with an existing matrix abstraction layer that already has unit tests that check results by comparing element values by index. E.g. assert that element [1,2] is close to 0.5. The abstraction layer is intended to hide the underlying matrix library from the rest of the application so that various matrix libraries can be swapped in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of `linear` looks like it's not going to support anything cleaner than defining something like

```
ind 0 = _x
ind 1 = _y
ind 2 = _z
ind 3 = _w
```

and then using it where you need it.  `linear` just isn't designed to support numerical indexing.

Comment: Ok, that seems like a reasonable compromise. Is the compiler smart enough to elide that kind of function, or does it add a little overhead due to the extra indirection?

Comment: The compiler should eliminate all of that at compile time when the constants are known and you're compiling with optimizations on.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to escape the fruit salad. By that I mean there's no easy way of indexing into an `V4` using an `Int`.

Every type that is an instance of `Ix` has two other types associated with it: the type of *indexes* into the type, and the type of the returned values. Haddock obscures things here, because those types are not displayed into the documentation! But after looking in the source code, they are the following:

```
type instance Index (V4 a) = E V4
type instance IxValue (V4 a) = a
```

The type of returned values is easy enough, it's just the type that parameterizes the `V4`. But what is that `E` in the index?

```
 newtype E t = E { el :: forall x. Lens' (t x) x }
```

Well, that's weird. It's not an `Int`, it's *a newtype wrapper for lenses going out of the `V4`*.

This means we have to use `ix` like this:

```
ghci> import Control.Lens
ghci> import Linear.V4
ghci> import Linear.Vector
gchi> over (ix (E _y)) (+ 1.0) (V4 1 2 3 4 :: V4 Float)
```

Another problem with your code is that `ix` returns a [`Traversal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html) that can't be used directly with `^.` or `view`, as it might target 0 elements, or more than one (the compiler isn't aware of the fact that, in the particular case of `V4`, a single element will always be targeted).

---

How to index into `V4` using a number? Here's a hack to do so, but it involves some techniques beyond beginner's level. The trick is to define an auxiliary typeclass `IxedV4`, and give instances to the type-level [nats](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:Nat) `1` to `4`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}
import Control.Lens
import Linear.V4
import Linear.Vector (E(..))
import GHC.TypeLits (Nat)

class IxedV4 (n::Nat) where
    -- Produce a wrapped lens from a type-level Nat
    -- The Nat will be specified using TypeApplications
    ixV4 :: Traversal' (V4 x) x

instance IxedV4 1 where
    ixV4 = ix $ E _x

instance IxedV4 2 where
    ixV4 = ix $ E _y

instance IxedV4 3 where
    ixV4 = ix $ E _z

instance IxedV4 4 where
    ixV4 = ix $ E _w
```

This lets us write the following:

```
bar :: V4 Float
bar = over (ixV4 @2) (+ 1.0) (V4 1 2 3 4 :: V4 Float)
```

Here that `2` following `ixV4` is a type, not a term! It doesn't exist at runtime. It's being applied to `ixV4` using a [type application](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=typeapplications#extension-TypeApplications).

Comment: Thank for you your answer. For the second part of your answer, you're using `2` as a type. Does that mean it's not a suitable method for runtime indexing? I probably should have made that clearer in my question.